# Laravel Auth Session logs me out after a period of time

Tags: php, laravel, session

Users in my application are getting logged out after a period of time although i have set the environment variable SESSION_LIFETIME = 525600

There are 100+ concurrent users in the application

The SESSION_DRIVER is set to file, i have read that changing to database and creating the php artisan session:table migration will make it work.

What could be the problem?

**Edit

Locally this does not happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So changing the `SESSION_DRIVER = database` and using `php artisan session:table` fixed the issue and now everything works as expected.